# Ignoring micrometer tracing for certain URIs

Tags: spring-boot

Both the snippets below offers similar functionality. Which is the right approach to choose from?

```
`@Bean
    ObservationRegistryCustomizer<ObservationRegistry> skipSecuritySpansFromObservation() {
        return (registry) -> registry.observationConfig().observationPredicate((name, context) ->
                !name.startsWith("spring.security"));
    }`


`@Bean
    ObservationPredicate skipSpringSecurityObservationPredicate() {
        return (name, context) -> !name.startsWith("spring.security.");
    }`
```

Tried to exclude micrometer tracing for certain URIs in Spring Boot 3. Need to choose the right way to exclude the patterns